# Regex match character after lazy grouping

Tags: regex

I want to match specifically the comma "," after the two groups ( AS) and (.*?).
I have a positive lookbehind that skips the AS but I cant get the grouping to skip the wildcard lazy group.

Regex:

```
(?<= AS)(.*?)(,)
```

Sample text

```
    SELECT     LEFT(CustomerCode, 5) AS SMSiteCode, SUBSTRING(CustomerCode, 6, LEN(CustomerCode) - 5) AS SMCustCode, SUBSTRING(AgreeNo, 6, LEN(AgreeNo) - 5) 
                  AS SMAgreeNo, CAST(SeqNo AS int) AS SeqNo, SUBSTRING(TrxDate, 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(TrxDate, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(TrxDate, 1, 2) AS TrxDate, TrxTime, 
                  CAST(Charge AS bit) AS Charge, CASE WHEN LEN(AnalysisCode) > 5 THEN SUBSTRING(AnalysisCode, 6, LEN(AnalysisCode) - 5) 
                  ELSE AnalysisCode END AS AnalysisCode, CAST(ISNULL(Description, N'') AS nvarchar(100)) AS Description, CAST(TaxAmt AS money) AS TaxAmt, 
                  CAST(TotAmt AS money) AS TotAmt, CAST(Match AS bigint) AS Match, CAST(Confirmed AS bit) AS Confirmed, CAST(Balance AS money) AS Balance, 
                  CAST(QtyBal AS money) AS QtyBal, CAST(ISNULL(Drawer, N'') AS nvarchar(50)) AS Drawer, SUBSTRING(DateBanked, 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(DateBanked, 4, 2) 
                  + SUBSTRING(DateBanked, 1, 2) AS DateBanked, CAST(ISNULL(BankBranch, N'') AS nvarchar(50)) AS BankBranch, CAST(Qty AS float) AS Qty, CAST(ISNULL(Narration, 
                  N'') AS nvarchar(100)) AS Narration, SUBSTRING(DateFrom, 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(DateFrom, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(DateFrom, 1, 2) AS DateFrom, SUBSTRING(DateTo, 7, 2) 
                  + SUBSTRING(DateTo, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(DateTo, 1, 2) AS DateTo, CAST(PrintNarration AS bit) AS PrintNarration, CAST(DiscAmt AS float) AS DiscAmt, 
                  CAST(ISNULL(CCAuthNo, N'') AS nvarchar(20)) AS CCAuthNo, CAST(ISNULL(CCTransID, N'') AS nvarchar(20)) AS CCTransID, CAST(UserLogin AS nvarchar(20)) 
                  AS UserLogin, CAST(Reconciled AS bit) AS Reconciled, SUBSTRING(DateReconciled, 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(DateReconciled, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(DateReconciled, 1, 2) 
                  AS DateReconciled, CAST(PrimaryKey AS bigint) AS PrimaryKey, SUBSTRING(InvDate, 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(InvDate, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(InvDate, 1, 2) AS InvDate, 
                  CAST(InvNo AS int) AS InvNo FROM         SomeDatabase.dbo.tblTransaction WHERE IsDate(trxTime) = 1
```

Comment: What is the programming language that you are using?

Comment: Testing it on Regexr, not necessarily for any language

Comment: With .NET regex you could use a vaiable width lookbehind: [`(?<= AS.*?),`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d+AS.*%3f%29%2c&i=+AS+SMSiteCode%2c+SUBSTRING%28CustomerCode%2c+6%2c+LEN%28CustomerCode%29+-+5%29+AS+SMCustCode%2c+SUBSTRING%28AgreeNo%2c+6%2c+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `\K`, but make sure to change `Javescript` in RegExr from top right of the screen to `PCRE`.

[image]

`\K` is defined as:

> Sets the given position in the regex as the new "start" of the match. This means that nothing preceding the K will be captured in the overall match.

With `\K`, you could try something like this:

`(?<= AS).*?\K(,)`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/X3AdbH/1/

Comment: That works, thanks! Still strange that we can't use generic lookaheads or non-capturing groups for that

Answer (score 1):

If `\K` is supported, you could get your matches without using a lookbehind and a capturing group by matching  `AS`  and use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match any char except a comma.

```
 AS [^,]+\K,
```

**Explanation**

- `AS`  Match space, AS and space
- `[^,]+` Match 1+ times any char except a comma
- `\K,` Forget what was matched and match a comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nTsVK3/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your expression is just fine, you maybe want to limit the first capturing group to some specific chars, if you wish, maybe looking like:

```
(?<= AS)([A-Za-z\d\s]+)(,)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SWPnFy/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/SWPnFy/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.